# Ercan airport and France visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, france, cyprus, northern-cyprus

We are Indian citizens who visited Cyprus this year. Entered through Larnaca and left from Ercan. Our passports were duly stamped at both ports.
Now I want to apply for a visa at the French embassy.
My question is this - will that Ercan stamp create a problem?

Comment: No, it's fine..

Comment: Thanks Coke. As the others pointed out, this question has been asked before. But three years back that was and govt. policies are very dynamic anyway. I wanted a current opinion. So thanks again.

Comment: Don't try to go to Cyprus or Greece on the same passport though

Comment: I won't do that :)